# RadioGroup is generating input[type=button] instead of type=radio

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, radio-group

When creating a `xtype=radiogroup`, the rendered element is using `input type=button` instead of `input type=radio`, I took the example from the doc, put it into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F85dK/) and the same happens. Tried this in Firefox and Chrome.

Why is not generating radio inputs, and how can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Hey Radu, why do you think you need to fix it? It is not a bug, probably it was easier to design the things on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct behavior. ExtJs is using `input type=button` to render radiogroup. These inputs are styled with css to look like real radio buttons.

As @matt has mentioned the reason for using `input type=button` is that a radio box's color, border and background cannot be styled using CSS.

In your fiddle inputs look like plain buttons because jsfiddle didn't load ext-all.css properly. If you add ext-all.css manualy (like I did in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/68Rx2/)) you will see that all inputs appear as if they were radio buttons.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the reason for using `input type=button` is that a radio box's color, border and background cannot be styled using CSS.

Comment: I forgot about this pitfall, the CSS was not loaded because the dev version of the app (not builded) by default is using the same CSS as the builded version (/build/production/app/...), I builded again and the CSS was loaded just fine. Thanks